# Unable to understand the SQL Exception- Ora Err Code :ORA-01000:

Tags: java, oracle, sqlexception, connection-leaks, ora-01000

I have a Java Class that's calling an SQL procedure to perform some DB operations.
Here's my Java method:

```
    public static void buildContent(String id) throws Exception{
    Connection conn = ExtractDB.getConnection();
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    log.debug("arguments for the procedure is=  "+id);
    try {
        cs = conn.prepareCall("{call CMS.relix.build_rp_data(?)}");
        cs.setString(1, id);
        cs.execute();
        if(cs!=null)
        {
            cs.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Exception while executing the procedure", e);                
    }
    finally{
        if(cs!=null)
        {
            cs.close();
        }
    }
}
```

After few processing, it prints below error in the log and gets hanged over there(I have to terminate the process manually in order to stop execution):

```
Ora Err Msg :-1000
Ora Err Code :ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
ORA-06512: at "CMS.relix", line 1700
ORA-06512: at line 1
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:168)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:208) ...
```

I have tried below solution:

After adding "**throw**" in the catch block, the process is not getting hanged now and it continues execution after printing same SQL error.

```
  catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error("Exception while executing the procedure", e);    
                throw e;
            }
```

I want your help to understand below points:

1. how adding "throw e" to the code, let the program continue even after error?
2. how to handle this error/exception to stop the processing and exit the program if this situation is encountered.

Comment: and your stored procedure do what? If you open a cursor, do you also close it? what is in "CTOW.RELP" on line 1700?

Comment: 1. you are calling `buildContent`  in a Methode where you a catch the exception and do nothing? you Need do handle the exception

Comment: Stored procedure fetches some data from DB, do the necessary update/delete. Yes there is a cursor in my procedure and its opened/closed as below:


    PROCEDURE build_rp_data (guid IN IDENTITY.LEXUS_GUID%TYPE) 
    AS
    csRelatedCases ref_cursor;
    OPEN csRelatedCases FOR
    ....
    CLOSE csRelatedCases; 
    END build_rp_data;

Comment: sorry m unable to format my code in above comment @hotfix

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close Connection, use try with resources block

```
log.debug("arguments for the procedure is=  "+id);
try (Connection conn = ExtractDB.getConnection();
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call CMS.relix.build_rp_data(?)}")) {
```

and remove `finally` block

Comment: After closing the connection as u suggested, I am getting 2 exceptions- Max cursors exceeded + java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection. THis happened probably because there is a parent method which is calling my buildContent() method plus 2 more methods. The other 2 methods are also calling SQL procedure. Hence i am getting Closed connection while executing procedures after closing connection.

Comment: @RichaSharma `ExtractDB.getConnection()` should return a new connection

Comment: Oh i missed this line of code- ExtractDB.getConnection();
As my code is built in java 1.6, I have closed the connection in finally block as below. please correct me if I am wrong: 

    finally{
     if(cs!=null)
            cs.close();
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();}

Comment: @RichaSharma first close conn and then cs